# Find the sequence convergence / limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $U_n$ be a sequence such that: $U_n = (c_n + d_n) / (c_n² + d_n²)$
where $\lim (c_n) = \lim(d_n) = 0$ and $c_n >0$, $d_n > 0$.

**Determine the limit of $U_n$?**

I tried to decompose the denominator as follows: $c_n² + d_n² = (c_n + d_n) (c_n + d_n) - 2 c_n d_n$
Since $\lim (c_n) = \lim(d_n) = 0 $  then  $ \lim(2 c_n d_n) = 0$ .
So the sequence $U_n$ is divergent ($ 0/0 $).

I don't know if my argumentation is right or not?

I thank you for your help.

Comment: A $\frac00$ form is not automatically divergent, so one has to argue more specifically to this sequence. Hint: $c_n+d_n \le 2\max\{c_n,d_n\}$ and $c_n^2+d_n^2 \ge \max\{c_n,d_n\}^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your help, using the hints it gives $(c_n+d_n)²/4 \le c_n² + d_n²$ so $U_n \le 4/(c_n + d_n) $ and $4/(c_n + d_n)$ tends towards infinity.
Is this right?

Comment: It's true that $4/(c_n+d_n)$ tends to infinity; but I realize that I misled you in my comments—to use the comparison test to conclude that the original sequence tends to infinity, we need a lower bound for $U_n$, not an upper bound. But similar inequalities should work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $c_n, d_n > 0$, one has $c_n^2 + d_n^2 \leq c_n^2 + d_n^2 + 2c_nd_n = (c_n + d_n)^2$.

So $$U_n = \dfrac{c_n + d_n}{c_n^2+ d_n^2} \geq \dfrac{c_n+d_n}{(c_n+d_n)^2} = \dfrac{1}{c_n+d_n}$$

Because $c_n + d_n$ tends to $0$, then $\dfrac{1}{c_n+d_n}$ tends to $+\infty$, hence by comparison $$\boxed{\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} U_n = +\infty}$$